# How do you Pivot a Large DataFrame in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

So, I'm having serious issues pivoting a very large dataframe (9,296,848 rows with ~100,000 articles) using pandas .pivot(). I'm unsure how to proceed from here. I've had a look at similar queries, but the suggestions either didn't work or seem very convoluted. Is there a way to do this by .groupby() or using some much quicker alternative?

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   customer article quantity
0  A        p       3
1  B        q       5
2  C        r       2
```

I'd like it to end up as:

```
   customer p    q    r
0  A        3    NaN  NaN
1  B        NaN  5    NaN
2  C        NaN  NaN  2
```

One thing I tried already was using:

```
df = df.set_index(['customer_id', 'article_id'])['quantity'].unstack('article_id')
```

But it didn't work. It throws up the same error as with .pivot(): Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow.

Any suggestions very much welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Does `pd.get_dummies(df['article'])` run with your dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will run, but you can try this alternative with [`pandas.get_dummie`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
df[['customer']].join(pd.get_dummies(df['article']).mul(df['quantity'], axis=0))
```

*NB. You can try to add `sparse=True` as parameter to `get_dummies`.*

Output:

```
  customer  p  q  r
0        A  3  0  0
1        B  0  5  0
2        C  0  0  2
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.pivot(index='customer', columns='article', values='quantity').rename_axis(columns='').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  customer    p    q    r
0        A  3.0  NaN  NaN
1        B  NaN  5.0  NaN
2        C  NaN  NaN  2.0
```

And for the Get Dummies method:

```
pd.concat([df.customer, pd.get_dummies(df.article).replace([0,1], [np.nan, df.quantity])], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  customer    p    q    r
0        A  3.0  NaN  NaN
1        B  NaN  5.0  NaN
2        C  NaN  NaN  2.0
```